# MPD mountpoint not showing up on icecast

Tags: audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, icecast, mpd

I am trying to setup MPD to work with Icecast to setup an internet radio streaming service.
MPD and Icecast do seem to work fine. However i donot see anything listed under Mountpoints on the dashboard on icecast. What needs to be done to enable the same

Here are my config files. Could you please help me on what i might be missing?

MPD Conf :

```
music_directory "/home/username/Downloads/Music"
playlist_directory "/home/username/.mpd/playlists"
db_file "/home/username/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file "/home/username/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file "/home/username/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file "/home/username/.mpd/mpdstate"
audio_output {
    type        "shout"
    encoding    "ogg"
    name        "my cool stream"
    host        "127.0.0.1"
    port        "8000"
    mount       "/stream.ogg"
    bind_to_address "127.0.0.1"

# This is the source password in icecast.xml
    password    "username123"

# Set either quality or bit rate
   quality     "5.0"
#    bitrate     "64"

    format      "44100:16:1"

# Optional Parameters
    user        "source"
#   description "here is my long description"
#   genre       "jazz"
} # end of audio_output

audio_output {
    type "alsa"
    name "username"
    driver "null"
}
```

Icecast config

```
<icecast>
    <!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
         on the server info page of the icecast web interface
         (server_version.xsl). -->
    <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>support@mydomain.com</admin>

    <!-- IMPORTANT!
         Especially for inexperienced users:
         Start out by ONLY changing all passwords and restarting Icecast.
         For detailed setup instructions please refer to the documentation.
         It's also available here: http://icecast.org/docs/
    -->

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>username123</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in with username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>username123</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>username123</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
    <!--
    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
    </directory>
    -->

    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
         It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
         listings. You MUST configure it properly for YP listings to work!
    -->
    <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8080</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
    -->


    <!-- Global header settings 
         Headers defined here will be returned for every HTTP request to Icecast.

         The ACAO header makes Icecast public content/API by default
         This will make streams easier embeddable (some HTML5 functionality needs it).
         Also it allows direct access to e.g. /status-json.xsl from other sites.
         If you don't want this, comment out the following line or read up on CORS. 
    -->
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </http-headers>


    <!-- Relaying
         You don't need this if you only have one server.
         Please refer to the config for a detailed explanation.
    -->
    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8080</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->


    <!-- Mountpoints
         Only define <mount> sections if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
    -->

    <!-- Default settings for all mounts that don't have a specific <mount type="normal">.
    -->
    <!-- 
    <mount type="default">
        <public>0</public>
        <intro>/server-wide-intro.ogg</intro>
        <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
        <authentication type="url">
                <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="foo" value="bar" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!-- Normal mounts -->
    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <public>1</public>
        <authentication type="htpasswd">
                <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
                <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webplayer.example.org" />
                <header name="baz" value="quux" />
        </http-headers>
        <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
        <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
        <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="headers"         value="x-pragma,x-token"/>
            <option name="header_prefix"   value="ClientHeader."/>
        </authentication>
    </mount>
    -->

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/usr/share/icecast</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/share/icecast/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast/admin</adminroot>
        <!-- <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
        -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
        -->
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
        <!-- The certificate file needs to contain both public and private part.
             Both should be PEM encoded.
        <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
        -->
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        <changeowner>
            <user>nobody</user>
            <group>nobody</group>
        </changeowner>
    </security>
</icecast>
```

MPD : Music Player Daemon 0.19.12

Error log:

```
Jan 05 15:10 : update: added /3185.mp3
Jan 05 15:10 : client: [5] closed
Jan 05 15:12 : client: [6] opened from [::1]:46344
Jan 05 15:13 : client: [6] closed
Jan 05 15:17 : pulse_output: Failed to enable "username" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
Jan 05 15:17 : client: [0] opened from [::1]:47352
Jan 05 15:17 : client: [1] opened from [::1]:47354
Jan 05 15:17 : client: [1] closed
```

Comment: The MPD log doesn't match the configuration. It's trying to connect to *::1* while the configuration states *127.0.0.1*. Restart MPD, try to figure it out. Also you can try to add a `<listen-socket><port>8000</port><bind-address>::</bind-address></listen-socket>` section.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it *should* work. Make sure that the password matches *source-password*.

Have a look at `/var/log/icecast/error.log` and `/home/username/.mpd/mpd.log`. If you need Icecast to be more verbose, set *loglevel* to 4 and restart.

Which version of MPD is this? Some of their versions exhibited rather weird/broken behaviour with Icecast.

Comment: MPD : Music Player Daemon 0.19.12
edited question to include errorlog

Answer (score 0):

Within your MPD.Conf file there are TWO audio_output{} sections.
And the second one could overwrite the frist one.
So delete/disable the part at the end of your config

```
> #audio_output {
> #    type "alsa"
> #    name "username"
> #    driver "null" }
```